# Flutter Web loads the initial page first even when loading URL with #/page

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, flutter-navigation

I am trying the standard navigation app provided here https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/named-routes.  Even if I open the browser to http://localhost:8080/#/second it builds page 1 and then replaces it with page 2 and even shows the user a back button.  I really want to take the user directly to the second page without "passing go". Any ideas please?

Here is the code again with some print's added

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    title: 'Named Routes Demo',
    routes: {
      '/': (context) => FirstScreen(),
      '/second': (context) => SecondScreen(),
    },
  ));
}

class FirstScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print ("Screen 1 building");
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('First Screen'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          child: Text('Launch second screen'),
          onPressed: () {
            // Navigate to the second screen using a named route.
            Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/second');
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SecondScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print ("Screen 2 building");
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Second Screen"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
          child: Text('This is screen 2, go to 1!'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you should convert second screen to a StatefulWidget  to add didChangeDependencies or initState and add your `Navigator.pop(context)`  to autumaticly go to FirstScreen

Comment: Thanks, my goal though is that to make sure when the app is initiated by opening `http://localhost:8080/#/second` then Flutter builds the second page directly without building the first page for a milisecond before.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the default route path in the `<FlutterProject>/web/index.html` on the line 14 `<base href="/">`.

It is by default set to "/"